# Inactive integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to solve inactive integral but output is coming same as input.
Any idea about how to solve inactive integral which is a function of 'r'. I am using version 12. The integration contains Hypergeometric and Meijer G functions.

```
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(r\)]\(\((\((28\ \
Hypergeometric2F1[2 - 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 2 + 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 4, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]]\ K[
       2]\ \((\(-10\)\ I\ \[Pi]\ \((\(-319\) + 234\ K[2])\) + 
        9\ \((\(-2552\) + 1364\ K[2] + 351\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(K[2]\), \(2\)])\) + 
        10\ \((\(-319\) + 234\ K[2])\)\ Log[\(-10\) + 
           9\ K[2]])\))\)/\((243\ \((\(-11\) + 
        7\ K[2])\)\ \((28\ Hypergeometric2F1[2 - 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 2 + 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 4, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]]\ MeijerG[{{}, {\(-
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]]\), 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]]}}, {{\(-2\), 1}, {}}, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]] + 13\ Hypergeometric2F1[3 - 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 3 + 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 5, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]]\ MeijerG[{{}, {1 - 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 1 + 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]]}}, {{\(-1\), 2}, {}}, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]] + 28\ Hypergeometric2F1[2 - 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 2 + 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]], 4, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]]\ MeijerG[{{}, {0, \(-
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]]\), 
\*SqrtBox[
FractionBox[\(15\), \(7\)]]}}, {{\(-2\), 1, 1}, {}}, 
\*FractionBox[\(7\ K[2]\), \(11\)]])\))\))\) \[DifferentialD]K[2]\)\)
```

`InputForm`

```
Integrate[(28*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - Sqrt[15/7], 2 + Sqrt[15/7], 4, (7*K[2])/11]*
    K[2]*(-10*I*Pi*(-319 + 234*K[2]) + 9*(-2552 + 1364*K[2] + 351*K[2]^2) + 
     10*(-319 + 234*K[2])*Log[-10 + 9*K[2]]))/(243*(-11 + 7*K[2])*
    (28*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - Sqrt[15/7], 2 + Sqrt[15/7], 4, (7*K[2])/11]*
      MeijerG[{{}, {-Sqrt[15/7], Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-2, 1}, {}}, (7*K[2])/11] + 
     13*Hypergeometric2F1[3 - Sqrt[15/7], 3 + Sqrt[15/7], 5, (7*K[2])/11]*
      MeijerG[{{}, {1 - Sqrt[15/7], 1 + Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-1, 2}, {}}, 
       (7*K[2])/11] + 28*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - Sqrt[15/7], 2 + Sqrt[15/7], 4, 
       (7*K[2])/11]*MeijerG[{{}, {0, -Sqrt[15/7], Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-2, 1, 1}, {}}, 
       (7*K[2])/11])), {K[2], 1, r}]
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a closed form solution should exist? Questions like this should always indicate why it is reasonable to expect a solution.

Comment: I just wanted to ask, how to solve inactive integral.

Comment: You can activate inactive integral by command : `Activate[integral]`.How to solve? We can't !.

Comment: The command NIntegrate[(28*
       ....
       MeijerG[{{}, {-Sqrt[15/7], Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-2, 
          1}, {}}, (7*K[2])/11] + 
      13*Hypergeometric2F1[3 - Sqrt[15/7], 3 + Sqrt[15/7], 
        5, (7*K[2])/11]*
       MeijerG[{{}, {1 - Sqrt[15/7], 1 + Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-1, 
          2}, {}}, (7*K[2])/11] + 
      28*Hypergeometric2F1[2 - Sqrt[15/7], 2 + Sqrt[15/7], 
        4, (7*K[2])/11]*
       MeijerG[{{}, {0, -Sqrt[15/7], Sqrt[15/7]}}, {{-2, 1, 
          1}, {}}, (7*K[2])/11])), {K[2], 1, 1.5}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 3] performs $0.264378\, -0.0204535 i $.